# How to check if bank account has already been added - Stripe Plaid ACH

Tags: php, stripe-payments, plaid

Is there a way to confirm that bank account has already been added before adding them to stripe. I'm using plaid to get the `btok_` token and then adding it as a new source to the stripe customer. I get this error when i try to add it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plaid docs have some info on preventing this on the Plaid side: https://plaid.com/docs/link/duplicate-items/.

The typical way of doing this works like this:

Make sure to put the Link flow behind a login, so that you have identifying information about your end-user when they start Link.

Store the value of the `mask` returned by the `onSuccess` callback in Link and associate it with the user.

Before calling `/item/public_token/exchange` on a public token, check the `mask` returned by onSuccess against previous `mask`s for the same user. If you find a match, the account that was just added is very likely a duplicate bank account; do not call `/item/public_token/exchange`.